# Nano not highlighting syntax anymore

Tags: 14.04, nano, syntax-highlighting

So I along with a few others are planning to start a company, and we are using an ubuntu server to host our website. Originally we put it on an old laptop and installed Ubuntu server 15.10. Now it is in a desktop server running on 14.04.3 LTS. When we moved our html files over to the desktop, nano stopped highlighting the syntax for the html files, even though the nanorc file in /etc/ has set to include html and so does the user's .nanorc file. This makes it difficult because all of the text is dark blue against a black background.

[image: User's .nanorc file]
[image: Nano not highlighting]

Comment: It could have to do with the downgrade to 14.04.3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/nano/html.nanorc /usr/share/nano/html.nanorc.bak
sudo nano /usr/share/nano/html.nanorc
```

in this folder replace contents with:

```
## Here is a short improved example for HTML.
##
syntax "HTML" "\.htm[l]?$"
color brightblue start="<" end=">"
color red "&[^;[[:space:]]]*;"
color yellow ""[^"]*"|qq\|.*\|"
color red "(alt|bgcolor|height|href|label|longdesc|name|onclick|onfocus|onload|onmouseover|size|span|src|style|target|type|value|width)="
```

That code is courtesy of scopatz at github url: https://github.com/scopatz/nanorc

Close and reopen terminal, then try nano into an html file.